# Chrome extension : can't use storage API in popup.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my popup.html, I have this

```
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

so then in my popup.js I try to run

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({"testkey": 'test'});
```

I got error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined`

I'd declare my permission properly :

```
  "permissions": [
    "http://*/*", "https://*/*","storage"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
```

Comment: Have you reloaded your extension properly after changing the manifest? Have you **double**-checked for typos? Are you by any chance trying to load `popup.html` outside the extension?

Comment: I reloaded and it worked, wierd when should I reload and when I need no to reload? because sometime I didn't reload I still see the changes I made.

Comment: Rule of thumb, _always_ reload after changes. Changes to HTML files do not require a reload since Chrome re-reads them, but changing most scripts requires a reload. And in case of content scripts - also a reload of the target page. And changes to the manifest also require reloads.

Comment: @Xan thanks, got it. Can you take a look at this question please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30195606/chrome-extension-got-blank-object-using-chrome-storage-sync-get

Answer (score -2):

Is it possible that it is trying to cal it before storage exists. try a

```
setTimeout('chrome.storage.sync.set({"testkey": 'test'});', 150);
```

to set it off after a delay to make sure it isn't related to load.
only thing is it will run that in global(window) scope. not sure if that matters.

Comment: It's a browser API call. By the time the JS context starts executing code, it exists.

Comment: normally just test this way to eliminate it on the off chance.

Comment: There is no off chance