# Chrome extension : got blank object using chrome.storage.sync.get?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("accounts", function (obj) {
    console.log(obj);
});
```

not sure what's wrong i have accounts as key and some value, but I got blank object using above code.

As you can see I did have something in my localstorage :

[image]

But why is it a blank object?

[image]

I have no permission issue, but why is it a blank object?

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing `localStorage` storage and `chrome.storage`.

Dev Tools only show `localStorage`; there are third-party extensions to Dev Tools that show the `chrome.storage`, e.g. [Storage Area Explorer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storage-area-explorer/ocfjjjjhkpapocigimmppepjgfdecjkb)

`localStorage`, `chrome.storage.local` and `chrome.storage.sync` are all different.

Comment: I got my stuff, but I do like this `var accounts = {};

chrome.storage.sync.get("accounts", function (obj) {
    accounts = obj;
});
    console.log(accounts);
` why the accounts is emtpy obj? I but when I console.log(accounts) within the storage scope it has something.

Comment: @AaronMusktin That's because the function is asynchronous.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/2336725

Comment: Do not ask follow-up question in comments.